# Cross-project time-record filtering using Active Collab 5 API

Tags: api, activecollab

For Active Collab team watching this tag.

I am working on a project that uses new Active Collab 5 API, I am having performance issue trying to run reports.

Example I try to build reports on date-range, and currently to achieve that I need to first run a call to get all projects.

Followed by a loop with this call:

```
API::get('/projects/'.$id.'/time-records/filtered-by-date?' . http_build_query(['from' => $from, 'to' => $to]))
```

However we have a large number of projects, in addition to high number of active projects we also need to filter Archived projects as well to get correct reports for billing.

Now I work with around 1500 projects in AC.

So I need to make 1500 API calls which takes a huge performance hit. Is there a way that you can possibly build something that would work along these lines.

```
API::get(/timerecords/filter-by-date);
```

with a possible passed parameter that will say (all, active, complited) project state.

Please let me know what you can do or if I have missed something in your documentation that already does this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is not a request that goes through all projects one by one, but a request that it tailored for cross-project reporting. Active Collab 5 has just the right API endpoint for that - `/reports/run`.

As an example, you can use this command to query time records and expenses from all active projects that were tracked today:

```
curl -H "X-Angie-AuthApiToken: YOUR-API-TOKEN" "http://your.activecollab.com/api/v1/reports/run?type=TrackingFilter&project_filter=active&tracked_on_filter=today"
```

Notice the route (`/reports/run`) and query arguments:

1. `type` - specify type of the report, in this case time and expense tracking report,
2. `project_filter` - specify project filter. Apart from `active`, other useful values of this filter are `completed` (for completed projects), `selected_1,2,3,4` (selected projects with a list of project ID-s), `client_1,2,3,4` (projects for clients with the given ID-s), `category_1,2,3,4` (projects in categories with the given ID-s),
3. `tracked_on_filter` - filter by the date when records were tracked. To target a particular date use `selected_date_YYYY-MM-DD` and to target a date range use `selected_range_YYYY-MM-DD:YYYY-MM-DD`.
4. `tracked_by_filter` - filter by who tracked the time. It can have various values, like `anybody`, `logged_user`, `selected_1,2,3`.

To list only time records, set `type_filter` to `time` (or to `expenses` if you want only expenses to be listed).

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go and I'll let you know.. BTW: good product!

Comment: Hi @Ilija I have tried this today and it returns a blank every time I tried different things including few different examples from your documentation on API but still nothing.. It does not crash, it returns response but its empty.

Comment: I added more code above please take a look maybe I am missing something.. Also "type": "AssignmentFilter"  ( I  get records for this ) so everything is set up correctly

Comment: I was playing around and I was looking in your original system what calls were you making and it turns out I needed to make call with 'include_all_projects' => true and the rest works fine

Comment: I've sent you the exact command. Names of parameters do matter (don't change them). Case of values does matter (don't change it). `include_all_projects` is not needed in `TrackingFilter`, but it may be in `AssignmentsFilter` (if you want filter to go through all projects, instead of just projects that you are assigned to).

Comment: Yeah I figured it out I thought at first you just indicated it as a place holder so I was changing the values :).. My bad!... Is it possible when I do this call to also get (Project-details, and project-tasks)  >>> When I display i am grouping by Client, Project, Task -> all time-records

Comment: Data that these reports return is as is. You can't force them to load more. Instead, do extra API requests (to fetch projects and their tasks), and than map the extra details that you need in your code.

Comment: Yeah that is what I have done, I was just wondering if you possible had that in your API. (Hvala puno!)

Comment: is there a same report but to select by EMPLOYEE ID ? other than this /users/3/time-records/filtered-by-date

Comment: I've added info about `tracked_by_filter` (#4).

Comment: hey how can i grab all projects that do not have category ID... I tried category_0 but that didn't work.. any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Sorry, there's no "uncategorized projects" filter. You need to grab all projects in a separate request, than filter them in your code and than apply that list of ID-s to tasks or time records filter. PS: That should of been a separate StackOverflow question I think…

Comment: yeah I already did it like that I am just concerned if we grow our project base to 1000s of open projects it might be a major performance hit. Thanks Ilija

Comment: It sounds like a premature optimization at this point. When you have thousands of active projects, get in touch and we'll figure something out. I will most probably recommend caching at your end + webhooks to keep the cache up to date.