# Requesting time records by user not working in Active Collab API?

Tags: php, api, activecollab

So I've been trying to request time records by user using the API (I use the php wrapper).

So for example for a given user id e.g. 34 (I do an earlier query to get all the user ids) I have been doing the following request (for specific dates):

users/34/time-records/filtered-by-date?from=2016-01-07&to=2016-04-08

As per the documentation query format:

https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/people/users-work/user-time-records.html

But this does not seem to work, it only returns the hours for one user (the rest zero) and I know the other users have definately logged time records!

The same query without the date filtering i.e.

users/34/time-records

Produces slight different results, but still returns zero for many users that I know have logged time records!

As I can't seem to get this working I'm looking at the more long-winded way of doing this of getting time records by project and then sorting by user - but that's far less efficient! If anyone has any insight into why the time records by user queries might not be working (or even to corroberate what I have found) that would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the most appropriate API, because it requires high permissions to work for users other than yourself. Please use time record reporting instead. More information can be found in this StackOverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790638/338473