# ActiveCollab 5.15 TrackingReport filter API returns 404

Tags: api, activecollab

The `TrackingReport` filter is returning a 404:

https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/reports-and-filters/expenses-filter.html

I'm using the following GET call: `/api/v1/reports/run?type=TrackingReport`

`X-Angie-ApplicationVersion` →5.15.122

Other filters run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TrackingReport` changed name to `TrackingFilter`. Check out this answer for a working example of tracking filter request:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790638/338473

Comment: Thanks, but why (after 3 years) is this not covered/updated in the online API documentation?