# ActiveCollab API filter results in API request

Tags: php, rest, api, activecollab

In its simplest form, I would like to return specific results, by means of a filter, but I can't see anything mentioned in the API documentation!

I'm using the Feather SDK (https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk) with this API https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/

One working example of the call returning **everything** is...

```
$tasks = $client->get('projects/123/tasks/')->getJson();
```

One would expect something like this to work?

```
$tasks = $client->get('projects/123/tasks/', [
   'task_list_id' => 12345
])->getJson();
```

Or maybe...

```
$tasks = $client->get('projects/123/tasks/?task_list_id=12345')->getJson();
```

However neither seem to be working.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Filtered tasks API is currently not available. By calling `/projects/:project_id/tasks` you get all open tasks in the project, and you can implement any required filtering on client's end, when you receive the response.

Comment: Any plans on making it available? Seems like a really useful feature surely?

Comment: No solid plans just yet.

Comment: any update on this? i want to make a list of task from all projects that are not completed and are asigned to the user. looping trough 100+ projects and for all of them requesting list of all task (which also contain more then required information) is so freaking stupid.

Comment: Project level task's API is no likely to be extended with filter, but you can try to use tasks report API instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33790638/338473.